# Pivot_wider but keeping IDs long

Tags: r, pivot

I basically just want to split up the questions/responses but keep several rows for IDs.

There are 5 questions which are repeated six times for each ID (but sometimes more/fewer times)... here I'm only showing how it would look if there were two questions that repeat twice per ID to give an idea of how the data looks currently:

```
ID          response          question
1              3                 1
1              4                 2
1              5                 3
1              1                 4
1              4                 5
1              1                 1
1              1                 2
1              4                 3
1              3                 4
1              2                 5
2              5                 1
2              2                 2
2              3                 3
2              2                 4
2              1                 5
2              4                 1
2              2                 2
2              5                 3
2              4                 4
2              4                 5
```

I've tried using pivot_wider which formats it like this:

```
tidyr::pivot_wider(data = df, names_from = question, values_from = response, names_prefix = "question")

ID       question1     question2     question3      question4     question5
<int>    <list>        <list>        <list>         <list>        <list>
1        <int [6]>     <int [6]>     <int [6]>      <int [6]>     <int [6]>
2        <int [6]>     <int [6]>     <int [6]>      <int [6]>     <int [6]>
```

But I need it to be formatted so that the IDs aren't merged, so it looks more like this, without concatenated responses:

```
ID       question1     question2     question3      question4     question5
<int>    <int>         <int>         <int>          <int>         <int> 
1        3             4             5              1             4
1        1             1             4              3             2
2        5             2             3              2             1
2        4             2             5              4             4
```

I actually removed another variable earlier on which labelled blocks of questions (i.e., the first 1-5 was 1, second 1-5 was 2, etc. for each ID) - would it help to retain that variable for the purpose of restructuring in the way I want to?
Thanks in advance.

Example data:

```
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), response = c(3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L
), question = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L
)), row.names = c(1:60), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Just pass to `unnest()`.

Comment: @caldwellst Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try a base R option with `reshape` + `ave` like below

```
subset(
  reshape(
    transform(
      df,
      q = ave(question, question, FUN = seq_along)
    ),
    direction = "wide",
    idvar = c("ID", "q"),
    timevar = "question"
  ),
  select = -q
)
```

which gives

```
   ID response.1 response.2 response.3 response.4 response.5
1   1          3          4          4          4          3
6   1          2          2          3          3          3
11  1          3          2          1          2          3
16  1          4          1          1          3          3
21  1          4          4          3          3          4
26  1          4          4          4          3          4
31  2          3          4          4          3          3
36  2          2          3          1          5          3
41  2          1          3          1          1          3
46  2          4          3          1          2          2
51  2          3          4          1          4          3
56  2          3          2          2          3          2
```